# Change locale immediately

Tags: android, locale

i want my app locale to be changeable in app. So i use this code in order to do that:

```
            String languageToLoad  = "fa";
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

but the thing is that i will see the changes after closing and opening my app manually. But i want it to occur immediately in the app after that lines of code.

i have tried by transferring my code to `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()` method and calling `onRestart()` after that lines of code. But it didn't work.

What should i do in order to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code..

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
```